# Intense GPU usage for animations playing over blurred background

Tags: javascript, html, css

Considering this paragraph from calibreapp.com:

> Browsers make optimizations by creating separate layers for elements
> with CSS transitions or animations on Position, Scale, Rotation and
> Opacity. When you have an animated element on its own layer, moving it
> around doesn’t affect the positions of surrounding elements, the only
> thing that moves is that layer. This way the browser avoids repaints
> and does only compositing.

Now imagine we want to blur the whole background, the blur animation starts progresses and finally it finishes, ok?

Now on this blurred background we want to add a simple scale animation like this: (note that this is a separate div with no connection with background we already blurred)

```
.beaton {
  animation: beatonAnime .5s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes beatonAnime {
  0%   { transform: scale(1); }
  100% { transform: scale(0.96); }
}
```

The confusing issue is:

Without that blurred background I get **1-2% GPU usage**.

With that blurred background (which is not animating now and has finished seconds ago) I get **68% GPU usage!!!**

As the paragraph said we should not see any difference between theses two as the blurred animation of background is not running when we add the scaling animation and they are in separate layers.

Here is the link to live example: (Note the GPU not CPU usage)

https://langfox.ir/test/beat/index.html

By the way this is the blur animation on the background:

```
.overlay {
  animation: overlayShow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes overlayShow {
  from {
    backdrop-filter: blur(0);
    background-color: rgba(35, 33, 36, 0);
  }
  to {
    backdrop-filter: blur(80px);
    background-color: rgba(35, 33, 36, 0.7);
  }
}
```

**Is there any solution for this?**

**NOTE:** There is no such issue when I use `filter: blur(80px)` instead of `backdrop-filter: blur(80px);`. So  what's wrong with backdrop-filter?

Comment: CSS blur will always use lots of CPU. An option would be to render everything (the movie AND the blur) with canvas instead of CSS. A canvas blur might be less CPU intensive, and you can create a screenshot. You can then display this screenshot which takes no CPU at all.  By the way, it also seems that the background still changes after the blur is applied (the colors change), so that can also be a cause of the CPU spike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i get the same problem when play an animation above a blurred overlay.My final solution is to get a static blur image,it's formate cant be .png and shoule be .jpg.Then i set the overlay css property as 'background-image:url('../xxx.jpg)'.Since the background of the overlay is static,it wont take a lot gpu resource.Its a silly solution.